# Web API Authorization Scenario

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have implemented ASP.NET WebSecurity Membership and WebAPI in the past but I have never used them both at the same time (never a need to).

Now, I am building a new site, and the client does not need visitors to Register or Login. So there will be no Membership.

The client does however want to be able to retrieve data via WebAPI. This data however may be sensitive and is not something that we want users or hackers to see, so how would I 'Authorize' my client - and only my client - so that she may make API requests, from a client (be it a WinForms desktop app, a mobile app, etc)?

Comment: I'd do it per-request, by passing in a GUID as APIKey

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri, could you elaborate a tiny bit more, please?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this; what sort of constraints do you have?  To keep people out, you need some sort of authentication, even if it's per device or per application install; Is your 'client' adverse to having some authentication in place from now on? You could conceivably use an API key to access the API, but that's not secure; someone could easily sniff the key. You could also use a Public/Private key combo, but that's a bit more difficult to set up. It all depends on what level of security you need and what you're willing to do to get it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Ideally I would just throw in an entire Membership system and then register my client (as role: admin) and take away the registration page so that future registrations are not possible - only logins. Would this acceptable? I just thought that this way was a bit of a "workaround" or "hack" given my clients request.

Comment: We don't know nearly enough about your application or its constraints to know whether or not that's a good approach.  Who uses this application? From where do they use it? (Remote? At the office at a specific set of IPs?)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker The users are just potential customers and I guess they'll be using it from wherever they feel like using it (home, office, toilet?) My client is not against authentication, so long as the user has no way of registering.

Comment: Then it sounds like you should create a special account that can create accounts or application keys, and issue those keys to people. So maybe they don't 'log in', but they can check the Key; and only allow the key to be used by a single person at a time (or tie it to a device or cookie, whatever).  Really this is just a broad overview , and reading more about your question, I don't think Stack Overflow is the best place for it. This is not concrete enough for us.

Comment: Thank you @Dimitri, I will look at it properly first thing in the morning, I can barely beep my eyes open right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something similar implemented in my public-facing API, where some of the methods are only allowed to be called by Administrators.

Administrative method signatures include string parameter that accepts Unique Identifier strings that I have previously assigned to administrator users.

Then on every method call I check, if provided API Key belongs to an administrator and throw unauthorized exception, if it doesn't, or respond to the call with data if it does.

Example method:

```
public decimal GetCompanyBalance(string APIKey, int CompanyId)
{
    if(!UserManager.GetByAPIKey(APIKey).IsAdmin){
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    return Company.GetBalance(CompanyId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri, this was a great help.